# How do apple trees grow?

Tags: fruit-trees, tree-care, apples

I have a young (3 year old) apple tree growing against a wall about 5 feet high. One branch is growing towards the wall and would be perfectly placed to go *over* the wall except it's about a foot too low.

I'm wondering as the tree grows will the branch actually move upwards, or will this branch's joining point on the trunk forever remain where it is and I need to remove/train the branch?

Answer (score 5):

The insertion point of the branch in the trunk will not move upwards, so you can leave it for few years and get apples next years, and only in few years you will create a branch above, or just prune it now and select a new branch.

Comment: Actually the branch can move upwards if it is trained - take a look at fan trained apple trees. But since apple trees grow from the tips of buds, where the branch meets the trunk will never move.

Comment: @Nic I interpreted the question (reading the last part of the question): if the insertion point of branch in the trunk could move upward.

Answer (score 5):

You could point it upward with a slip knot on a rope that's attached to something on the roof if it's not too close to the house, and still bendable enough. from what I've read it will only get fatter over time, and I did form some of my own branches that were pointed downward that way.